# Delay changing content of div in AJAX beforeSend jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX call like before:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'testurl.php',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        // Change content of div after 3 seconds
           $('#wait_more').delay(3000).html('Content will appear soon, please be patient...');
    },
    success: function(data){
        // Do stuff on success
    }
});
```

I'm trying to display some text in a div with id `wait_more` after 3 seconds since the start of AJAX request. I tried to add the following code inside the before send:

```
$('#wait_more').delay(3000).html('Content will appear soon, please be patient...');
```

But this doesn't work. The text is displayed as soon as the ajax request starts (not after 3 seconds as I want).

Any idea how I can achieve this?

**Please note** that I also tried `setTimeout` inside `beforeSend` like the following:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#wait_more').delay(3000).html('Content will appear soon, please be patient...');
}, 3000);
```

But that still doesn't work. In this case, the message is displayed at the end of ajax call (not what I want).

Comment: delay is for effect queue, html is not part of that

Comment: How can I achieve this then? Even setTimeout is not working.

Comment: @user765368 try like this setTimeout(function () {
    $('#wait_more').html('Content will appear soon, please be patient...');
}, 3000);

Comment: Well is your Ajax call taking 3+ seconds to run??? My guess is the call completes and then your timeout finally runs.